# Binding datepicker after pjax success results in infiniteloop

Tags: jquery, datepicker, yii2, pjax

so i have this problem i have input with class date-time, i`m binding datepicker to it, with:

```
$(".date-time").datepicker();
```

Everything works fine, after filtering in kartik grid view, as it supposed date picker getting unbinded ( cuz of pjax reload ). I`m trying to bind it again, with:

```
$(document).on("pjax:success", function() {
    $("#calendartasksearch-starttime").datepicker();
});
```

and i`m getting infinite looped ~~

My grid view configuration:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'pjax' => true,      
    'pjaxSettings' =>
        [
            'neverTimeout'=>true,
            'options'=>['id'=>'pjax-data'],
            'loadingCssClass' => false,
        ], 
    'bootstrap' => true,
    'condensed' => true,
    'responsive' => true,
    'showFooter' => true,
    'hover' => true,
    'showPageSummary' => true,
    'resizableColumns' => false,
    'columns' => $columns,
    ]);
```

Column with input filter:

```
[
'label' => 'Task Start',
'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
'attribute' => 'startTime',
'filter' => Html::activeInput('text', $searchModel, 'startTime', ['style' => 'text-align: center', 'class' => 'form-control date-time']),       
'value' => 'startTime',
'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;' ],
],
```

edit.

ok i managed to get out of infinite loop with:

```
$(document).one("pjax:success", function() {
    $(".date-time").datepicker();
});
```

but still i can re-initiate plugin

Answer (score 1):

Ok i resolved it myself.

First of all the problem is that you can't reinitiate two .datepicker after ajax refresh, it`s just going into infinite loop [ even if you have seprate name + id + class for each element ].

The way that i fixed the problem is:

Initiate one file with widget and second with activeInpute, like below:

```
         [
            'label' => 'Task Start',
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
            'attribute' => 'startTime',
            'filter' => DatePicker::widget(['model' => $searchModel, 'attribute' => 'startTime', 'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'options' => ['id' => 'date-time2','style' => 'text-align: center', 'class' => 'form-control']]),
            'value' => 'startTime',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;', 'class' => 'datepicker' ],
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Task End',
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;' ],
            'attribute' => 'endTime',
            'filter' => Html::activeInput('text', $searchModel, 'endTime', ['style' => 'text-align: center', 'id' => 'date-time', 'class' => 'form-control']),
            'value' => 'endTime',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;' ],
        ],
```

At the start i initaite date picker in active input with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date-time").datepicker({
        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
        orientation: "bottom auto"
    });
});
```

After ajax refresh i reinitiate both datepickers with:

```
$(document).on("pjax:success", function(){
    $("#date-time, #date-time2").datepicker({
        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
        orientation: "bottom auto"
        });
});
```

If anoyone know better way to do this, plz elaborate.